# When I press enter and create a new line in vim while editing CSS, it gives me two tabs instead of just one

Tags: vim, tabs, macvim, auto-indent

I debated with myself whether to post it on SuperUser but I did it here.
When I have this in CSS, editing it in VIM:

```
#container {
```

then I press Return at the bracket to give me a new line, it sends the cursor two tabs to the left on the next line:

```
#container {
        |
```

Instead of like this, how I want it.

```
#container {
    |
```

how could I edit the .vimrc file to give me only one new tab on the next line instead of two?

My .vimrc file.

```
set ts=4
imap <C-Return> <CR><CR><C-o>k<Tab>
set cindent
set nocompatible
filetype indent plugin on
syntax on
set hidden
set wildmenu
set showcmd
set hlsearch
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set autoindent
set nostartofline
set ruler
set laststatus=2
set confirm
set visualbell
set t_vb=
set mouse=a
set cmdheight=2
set number
set notimeout ttimeout ttimeoutlen=200
set pastetoggle=<F11>
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=1

map Y y$
nnoremap <C-L> :nohl<CR><C-L>
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is your setting? can you past the output of :set?

Comment: Show us your vimrc if you want help on your vimrc.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, had to leave my computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is that your `shiftwidth` is twice your `tabstop`.  You are also setting `tabstop` twice, once at the top to 4 and again at the bottom to 1.

Try setting `shiftwidth` to the same at `tabstop`, there really aren't many cases that you'd want these two to be different.